# Autofac. Register HttpContext.Session per tenant

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi tenant application. For now what I want to achieve is obtaining a **unique instance of HttpContext per tenant**.

1. Each tenant has its own database.
2. All tenants share same functionality (There aren't any tenant X specific controllers)
3. There is a master database for querying all tenants (So before accessing tenant's settings (eg:connectionString) there must be at least one hit to master database).
4. Tenant is identified from **RequestContext** `RouteData.Values["tenant"]`

Here is some *simplified* code so please do not focus on the architecture:

**Route url pattern:**`{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Delegates for BuildSessionFactory and GetSession are declared under Application_Start()
        // Registers SessionFactory to be Singletone per Tenant
        builder.Register(BuildSessionFactory).As<ISessionFactory>().InstancePerTenant();
        builder.Register(GetSession).As<ISession>().InstancePerRequest();
        // This is the module responsible for mapping HttpContextBase to HttpContextWrapper and other mvc specific abastractions
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());

        var container = builder.Build();
        // Build multitenant container
        var mtc = new MultitenantContainer(new RouteDataTenantIdentificationStrategy("tenant"), container);
      
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(mtc));
    }

    private ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(IComponentContext context)
    {
        return new NHibernateConfiguration().BuildConfiguration().BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private ISession GetSession(IComponentContext context)
    {
        return context.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession();
    }
```

**HomeController** sample:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private readonly HttpContextBase _context;

    public HomeController(ISession session, HttpContextBase context)
    {
        _session = session;
        _context = context;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Setting up HttpContext.Session["testSessionKey"] only for tenant1
        if (_context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["tenant"] as string == "tenant1")
        {
            _context.Session.Add("testSessionKey","Some value specific to tenant1 only");
        }
        using (var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            var tenants = _session.Query<Tenant>().ToList();
            transaction.Commit();
            return View(tenants);
        }
    }
}
```

#### The Workflow:

**Remark**: *The code above ignores the true existance of the tenant. It just satisfies the dependencies according to the `RouteDataTenantIdentificationStrategy("tenant")` class definition (identification by RouteData nothing exceptional).*

- Now when I'm accessing the url: `/tenant1/Home/Index` a `HttpContext.Session['testSessionKey']` is added.
- When I try to acces something like `/otherTenant/Home/Index` the `HttpContext.Session['testSessionKey']` is still there.

#### Question 1:

How to achieve Unique HttpContext per tenant using Dependency Injection with **Autofac**?

#### Question 2:

How to achieve something more than a HttpContext? Lets say a WorkContext which includes the tenant's HttpContext

***If something is unclear please ask and I'll provide necessary clarifications. Thank you!***

Comment: Just to be clear, HttpContext is a per-request entity. You appear to want to populate properties in session on a per-tenant basis, but you don't (shouldn't) want HttpContext per tenant because you can't share HttpContext across requests.

Comment: Yes you're right. I actually meant per tenant's request sorry. The main problem is my misunderstanding towards how HttpContext actually works. One one hand it's said that is tied to the current thread, on the other it contains properties such as `Session`, `User`, `Items` + some extension methods appeared like `.GetOwinContext()` which are shared globally (eg: Session). All I want to achieve is isolating each tenant's 'AppContext/WorkContext' in order to avoid crossing values. Maybe I'm overengineering here If so please point me to the right direction. Thank you Travis.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you push the customization of the context values to the registration of `HttpContextBase`. Instead of using the `AutofacWebTypesModule`, use your own registration:

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
  var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
  var strategy = c.Resolve<ITenantIdentificationStrategy>();
  // Update the context here
  return httpContext;
}).As<HttpContextBase>()
.InstancePerRequest();
```

That means you should also have your tenant ID strategy registered in the container, but that's pretty easy.

(Sorry for the short snippet; I'm on my phone traveling.)

Comment: I was 99% confident, that you'll be the one who will answer first! :)). I've added a comment after yours. When you got some time, could you please take a look. Thank you! P.S. Happy travelling!

Comment: I think the answer I posted should work. Given my current constraints (no machine) it's probably best I'd you try it... or supply the pattern, at least... and see where it gets you. Lambda is the secret here.